# Jquery - Ajax : Unhandled multiple clicks event with ajax button "on Click method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button where i'm injecting an ajax request to a distant web service.

the traitment takes effects after checking a condition given from the success of another ajax request **(thats why i am usung "ajaxSuccess")**

*My fonction looks like this :*

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn', function (e) {
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {

   if (settings.url === window.annonce.route.testService) {
              xhr = xhr.responseJSON;
              var msg = {},
                    if (xhr == 1) {   //case of traitement to be done
                    msg["attr1"] = attr1;
                    msg["attr2"] = attr2;
                    msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
                    console.log(msg);

                    $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: servicePostulation,
                    data: {msg: msg},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                       console.log(data);
                       $("#btn").addClass("active");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
                    }
                 });
               }
           }
       })

}
```

I my case , the **"console.log(msg)"** shows me a *multiple sending of data msg* , which means a multiple clicking events , **and that's exactly the problem i wanna evitate,**

i have tried many solutions with the **" $('body').on('click')**  like :

1. e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                   e.preventDefault();
2. stopPropagation()
3. one()
4. off()
5. unbind()

**but nothing works , so is there any further solution or explication ??**

Comment: On each time you click button, you are binding new `ajaxSuccess` event. So why are you nesting event?

Comment: the ajaxSuccess isn t for that ajax request it s for another ajax call and am using it to get some value , it s not the same ajax call

Comment: BUT why are you nesting this event inside a click event? Now each time you click, you add a new `ajaxSuccess` event which would be fired x times, depending how many times you clicked on `#btn`. Just don't set this event inside any other one, and see if it is your issue. Because anyway, your question is missing context regarding your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggest is to disable the button when user click and then enable the button when ajax complete.

**onClick:**

```
$('#btn').prop("disabled", true);
```

**Ajax complete/success:**

```
$('#btn').prop("disabled", false);
```